# Difference between OpenJDK 10 and Java SE 10 Reference Implementation

Tags: java

What exactly is the difference between the two versions described below?

From http://jdk.java.net/10/

## JDK 10.0.1 General-Availability Release

This page provides production-ready open-source builds of the Java Development Kit, version 10.0.1, an implementation of the Java SE 10 Platform under the GNU General Public License, version 2, with the Classpath Exception.

---

From http://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/10

## Java Platform, Standard Edition 10 Reference Implementations

The official Reference Implementation for Java SE 10 (JSR 383) is based solely upon open-source code available from the JDK 10 Project in the OpenJDK Community.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Reference Implementation is a 'prototype or "proof of concept" implementation of a Specification', in this case the Java SE 10 Platform JSR. As such, it doesn't get any further updates, unless the specification itself needs to be updated. Its target audience are specification writers, and implementation developers, rather than actual users.

The GA release, on the other hand, receives at least two updates for critical issues, e.g. time zone fixes, P1 bug fixes, security issues, etc. - it's suitable for development and production use.

Answer (score 2):

The General-Availability Release is designed for actual use by programmers and developers, and receives security updates. The Reference Implementation is for JVM developers who want a reference JVM that is conforming to the specification that they can compare their work to.

In any case you want to use the GAR builds.